# Nest.js Inject kafka client to the service

Tags: apache-kafka, microservices, nestjs, kafkajs

I have a Nest.js microservice application. For message broker between MS I'm using kafka.

Now I want to inject this same connection inside health service to test it's state. I don't want to create a new client and new connection. I need the one which is created in main.ts.

```
const microserviceOptions = {
  transport: Transport.KAFKA,
  options: {
    client: {
      clientId: `id`,
      brokers: [brokers],
    },
    consumer: {
      groupId: 'group-id',
    },
  },
};
```

Ideally I would love to get kafkajs client directly from nestjs, to create producers and consumers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If anyone is stuck searching for this. I extended existing kafka transprot strategy into a custom transporter and imported that.

I extended ServerKafka into a new class CustomServerKafka. New class only had getConsumer and getProducer, because consumer and producer were protected in ServerKafka.

I used singleton class creator to get access to active consumer

Comment: If you could publish some example that'd be really helpful